# NodeJS: avoiding circular dependency in mutually dependent modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection, module

#### Short Form:

What's the nodeJS idiom for setting up mutual dependencies among modules without creating circular references?

#### Details:

In nodeJS, assume I have two object classes: `Thing` and `ThingController`.

`ThingController` is responsible for creating and maintaining a library of `Thing` objects:

```
\\file: thing-controller.js
"use strict";

var Thing = require('./thing');

var ThingManager = function() {
  this._things = new Map();
};

// ...etc...

module.exports = ThingManager;
```

And the Thing module might look like this:

```
\\file: thing.js
"use strict";

var Thing = function(id, name) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = title;
  this.siblings = undefined;
}

// ...etc...

module.exports = Thing;
```

All of this works fine as long as `Thing` never needs to reference `ThingManager`.

But what if I want to add `Thing.prototype.findSiblings` or some such function that requires calling `ThingManager`?

What's the nodeJS idiom for setting up mutual dependencies without creating circular references?  Is this a use case for dependency injection, and if so, what's the approved approach?

Comment: You'd have to show us an actual example of a real-world need for a circular reference for us to advise.  Without a specific example, the answer is you refactor (often breaking code out into a third file that both can include) to stop having the circular reference. But, sometimes the answer is that you change your design to avoid it too. Keep in mind that you can call methods all day long on some other object without importing that class.  You just can't call the constructor yourself without importing the class first. So, a `thingManager` can call methods on `things` without importing `things`.

Comment: Sometimes you call `require()` lazily (not at module init time).  There are lots of possible solutions.  Which one to use depends entirely upon the specifics of the particular code.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solution is to just put the two co-dependent classes in the same file.  They depend on each other anyway so you can't use one without the other.

Comment: Let's see. I have a module called `files` that has lots of file utilities in it. And a module called `exe` that has utilities for looking at the PATH and node_modules folder structures and finding exes and cmds and such and running them. Clearly `exe` imports `file` - it's doing all kinds of walking around in the file system looking for stuff. And in a few places of `file` it uses `exe` (say, to run robocopy).

Thing is, importing the two modules into one another (circularly) actually seems to work just fine.